# How to call a Windows Batch Script (BAT file) with Python in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, oracle-dbms, batch

I have a windows batch file (.bat) which executes some Oracle Queries.

I want to integrate this Batch Script in a QGIS Plugin.

How can I do this with Python?

The cx_Oracle Python extension module is not an option within my infrastructure here.

Comment: Here is an answer with an example that should do what you intend do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818774/executing-a-subprocess-fails

Comment: Your question is not too clear. What exactly is it that you want to achieve ? Python lets you execute any OS command, including shell scripts. Is it that you want to run a script that calls SQLPLUS to submit some SELECTS and you want read the results back ? You can just redirect the output of the script to a file, then read and parse it using Python. A pretty complex process when you could just run the queries directly from Python. Why is cx_oracle not possible ?

Comment: There are some restrictions from our IT department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to call my Batch Script:

```
import os
os.system("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c z:\Scripts\myscript.bat")
```

Thank you Matte for the comment. The link puts me on the right path:
["How to open a program with cmd.exe from Python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882553/how-to-open-a-program-with-cmd-exe-from-python) on stack overflow.